# How can I access objects of an array in a query?

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, position, salt-stack

I am currently working on a project for my school. The goal is to analyze logsfiles that are generated by salt-stack. I have already setup a MongoDB and the MONGO_FUTURE_RETURN Returner in salt-stack.
I want to analyze the logfiles via a python script. Eveything is connected and basic queries such as db.saltReturns.find() work fine.

Since I do not want to rewrite the retuner and my programm needs to access different objects I need something like "Object.Everything.nestedObject".

To clarify what I mean I have attached a snippet of data and will show you what I would want to access.

I have already tried to use $, $each and $[] - none of them solved my problem.

```
                "fun_args" : [ ],
                "jid" : "20190423135733454092",
                "return" : {
                        "cmd_|-sssd-ldap-cmd-pam-auth-update-bugfix_|-/usr/local/bin/bugfix-682662-sh_|-wait" : {
                                "comment" : "No changes detected",
                                "start_time" : "13:58:22.852410",
                                "result" : true,
                                "duration" : 0.016,
                                "__run_num__" : 26,
                                "__sls__" : "sssd-ldap.install",
                                "changes" : {

                                }
                        },
"pkg_|-salt-minion-required-packages_|-salt-minion-required-packages_|-installed" : {
                                "comment" : "All specified packages are already installed",
                                "name" : "python-concurrent.futures",
                                "start_time" : "13:58:18.915102",
                                "result" : true,
                                "duration" : 24.703,
                                "__run_num__" : 5,
                                "__sls__" : "salt-minion.install",
                                "changes" : {

                                },
                                "__id__" : "salt-minion-required-packages"
                        }
...
                }
```

In my script I would like to access:

```
"full_ret.return.[all].comment"
```

All I need is a positional operator that can replace the `[all]` placeholder.

Comment: This is what I currently have as a query:

`db.saltReturns.find({},{"_id": 0, "minion": 1, "full_ret": 1, "full_ret.fun_args": 1, "full_ret.retcode": 1,"full_ret._stamp": 1, "full_ret.fun": 1, "full_ret.id": 1, "full_ret.return": 1,"full_ret.return.$[].comment": 1})`

And this is the error that I keep getting:

`Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Positional projection 'full_ret.return.$[].comment' does not match the query document.",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched many forums and documentations but could not find a wildcard operator for mongoDB queries. Sadly this seems to be a feature that will not be implemented.